# Safari unexpectedly randomly glowing during transitions

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition, glow

I've encountered an unexplainable problem with Safari.
I'm using Transit Js Library to use CSS3 transitions with jquery. It actually works but during  opacity transitions some elements in the page glow, even those not involved in the transition.
Does anybody know why could this happen, and if there's anything I can do to prevent it?

My website is http://www.cubbit.net if someone wants to see the problem..

Thank you very much indeed!

Matteo

Comment: ^^ edited. That done, does someone has to connect via FB to see your problem? If yes then please provide another way to see it...

Comment: Ok, I will work on it! Sorry, that's true...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the active-problem. When forms are focused, they get an outline. And also does normal divs now.

So if you (in your CSS-file) adds the following:

```
div, p, b, i, u, strong, em { /* add more if needed */
    outline: none;
}
```